# Why is the preposition "into" used in "come into the upper right corner of the screen." instead of "on"?

Tags: prepositions

This context comes from the movie "Fight Club" (1999).

JACK: *Tyler was a night person. While the rest of us were sleeping, he worked. He had one part-time job as a projectionist. A movie doesn't come all in one big reel, it's on a few. Someone has to be there to switch the projectors at the exact moment when one reel ends and another reel begins. If you look for, you see little dots **come into** the upper right corner of the screen*.

I assume that "*come*" here means...

To move into view; appear: *The moon came over the horizon.*(American Heritage Dictionary)

...and if it does, the sentence could be transformed into "*you see little dots appear into the upper right corner of the screen*" but it doesn't sound right, "*appear on the upper right corner*" would be fine form me. Why is it "*into*" and not "*on*". Is it because they appear "*inside*" of the are of the screen? I could not find a definition for this preposition that would fit this context.

Comment: It's only *casual speech* - not worth wasting time analyzing it to that level of precision. He could just as easily have said ***appear in, appear at, appear on,...*** Assuming you've transcribed it accurately, you should easily be able to see that ***If you look for**, you should...* isn't syntacxtically valid anyway (look for ***what***?). I don't really think there's enough here to justify a formal "answer". Please stick to asking about things for which you can find ***more than one example.***

Comment: ...note that the speaker is probably being distracted by thinking of usages like ***come into view***, if that helps you get your head around the "aberrant" choice of preposition

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would go so far as to say: in this and many similar questions, the casual speech conflates or elides common phrases, often to omit repeated words, like "little dots *come into [view in]* the upper...". But meanwhile, StaticBounce, even if we insist on a literal reading, "come into" doesn't always mean motion. The moon "comes into" the sky by sliding into view, but at twilight, stars "come into" the sky by appearing out of nowhere.

Comment: Dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-into

Comment: @AndyBonner: On account of that ***If you look for***, I quickly downloaded a copy of a subtitle file for the movie, which didn't include those 4 words at all. But as it happens, I have a copy of the movie itself on "backup storage", so I checked that. He very clearly enunciates *If you look for **it**, you can see...* Whatever - I don't attach any significance to the fact that he says ***come into* [position]** rather than the more common phrasing ***appear in/at** [position]*. It's just another case where this OP in particular is trying to attach "meaning" at too low a level.

Comment: ...and there should be ***zero** chance* of his words not being understood in total. There's a brilliant example of ["breaking the fourth wall"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_wall) while Edward Norton is delivering these lines, in a cutaway to a back view of Tyler in his projection booth ***pointing to the dots*** as they appear (in the top right). An excellent example of creative "Show and Tell"!

Comment: "Come" does not colocate with "on" to express the appearance of an object.  However, you could say "appear on" or "appear in".

Comment: Also, we say **in the corner**.

Comment: It's maybe anthropomorphizing the dots, suggesting that rather than appearing they walk into the frame or otherwise move themselves into the frame like fish swimming in or bugs crawling in or something. "Came over the horizon" is the same - it's not that the moon is literally moving (although it is moving gradually this is too slow to be noticeable), it's that the rotation of the earth is changing our view. But you use a different preposition for something moving above and something moving inside something.

Answer (score 1):

"Into" will generally be used when referring to content that is bounded.

It simply reinforces the fact that the subject (cursor, dots etc) is constrained to the field of view, (computer screen, movie screen etc).

This also applies to the moon example, wherein the bounding element is your own physical field of view, (what your eyes can see).

Comment: I would add that "Come on the <object>" is never used to indicate a sudden appearance to this answer.

Comment: @BadZen - yes and no, it could be used in an unbounded context, e.g. "come onto the horizon", "come on the radar" etc.